# line delete function does not work well

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic-forms

I have created a table that contains a dynamic form, so when clicked add button will display a new row with the same form each line. and I have also made ​​the switch to clear the form, but it is not going well. anything because there are other functions in the action to remove that line. The following coding that I have made.

html:

```
<table class="table table-striped area-table tabel-form-makanan">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nama Makanan</th>
            <th>Jenis Makanan</th>
            <th>Harga Makanan</th>                            
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="nama-makanan[]" style="height: 30px; width: 280px;" class="nama-makanan" placeholder="ketikkan nama makanan"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="id-makanan[]" class="id-makanan"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" readonly name="nama-jenis-makanan[]" style="height: 30px; width: 280px;" class="nama-jenis-makanan" placeholder="nama jenis makanan"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" readonly name="harga-makanan[]" rel="hargaMakanan" style="height: 30px; width: 280px; text-align: right;" class="harga-makanan" placeholder="harga satuan makanan"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="btn hapus-baris-makanan" style="display: none;"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button class="btn btn-primary tombol-tambah-makanan" type="button" style="float: right; margin-right: 10px;">Tambah</button>
```

javascript for dynamic form:

```
$('.tombol-tambah-makanan').on('click', function(){
    var tr = '<tr>\n\
                <td><input type="text" name="nama-makanan[]" style="height: 30px; width: 280px;" class="nama-makanan" placeholder="ketikkan nama makanan"/><input type="hidden" name="id-makanan[]" class="id-makanan"/></td>\n\
                <td><input type="text" readonly name="nama-jenis-makanan[]" style="height: 30px; width: 280px;" class="nama-jenis-makanan" placeholder="nama jenis makanan"/></td>\n\
                <td><input type="text" readonly name="harga-makanan[]" rel="hargaMakanan" style="height: 30px; width: 280px; text-align: right;" class="harga-makanan" placeholder="harga satuan makanan"/></td>\n\
                <td><a class="btn hapus-baris-makanan"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a></td>\n\
            </tr>';
    $("table.tabel-form-makanan tbody").append(tr);                  
});
```

javascript for delete form:

```
$('.tabel-form-makanan').on( 'click', '.hapus-baris-makanan', function(){
    var parent = $(this).parents('tr');
    var harga = $('.harga-makanan', parent).val();
    pengurangan_pesanan(harga);
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

other javascript:

```
function pengurangan_pesanan(price) {
        if (subtotal > 0) {
            var kembali = 0;
            subtotal -= parseFloat(price);
            $('.subtotal').val(subtotal);
            if (cek_bayar != isNaN || cek_bayar != 0) {
                kembali = cek_bayar - subtotal;
                $('.kembali').val(kembali);
            }
        }
}
```

Do you have a solution to this problem, I really need it. thank you

*demo : http://jsfiddle.net/daniwarrior/ANfFe/1/

Comment: if you have more than one function removing the line we would need to see both functions...create a demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates the problem

Comment: so what do you want explain clearly???????